# How can I obtain the values in a recursive cost function?

Tags: function, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

I need your advice to compute the values in a recursive cost function. For example, if I have the follow cost function,

[image]

where [image], 
[image], k=2 and

[image].

The functions g(i) and g'(i) are discrete valued. Once explained this example. How can I compute the cost values using dmin = -1 and dmax= 4?

Next figure can help to understand what I want to compute,

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what help you need.  You have the algorithm, the inputs, and the required **g** functions.  You have all the functional definitions in convenient form.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prune. The problem is that I don't know how to compute C properly due the recursively. For example, if C(1,-1) =min_d_(-2){C(-2,d_(-2))+wS(-1,d_(-2))}+Delta(1,-1). How works the recursion inside min? And d_(-2) what value takes? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that **min(d(i-1)) is notation meaning *the minimum over the d values from 0 to (i-1)*.  Therefore, there is no -2 case.

The recursion inside **min** is as any other recursion: you reduce i by 1 and call the **C()** and **S()** functions again, recurring until you reach the base case.

This is not a short computation, since each call to **C** spawns two calls.

Overall, I can't give you any code, because the notation for **S** is unfamiliar to me: it uses **d** both with and without a subscript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prune. Could you tell me if am I wrong in this example [link](http://tinyurl.com/jqxwxv9)?

Comment: Not any time this week; this is asking for a non-trivial amount of alternate coding or hand-checking.